# Visible iOS time picker in ionic 1.x app

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, timepicker

Is it possible to have a visible "spinner wheel" time picker for ionic without first having to click on an input to display the timepicker? Or alternatively, is it possible to display the native iOS time picker without having to use an input and have the time picker visible constantly?

[Screenshot from the events section of the iOS FaceBook app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl5eq.png)

Please see image for reference.